# VBA to find multiple files

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which finds file names(along with file paths) based on search string.This code works fine in finding single files. I would like this macro to find multiple files and get their names displayed separated using a comma.

```
Function FindFiles(path As String, SearchStr As String)

          Dim FileName As String   ' Walking filename variable.
          Dim DirName As String    ' SubDirectory Name.
          Dim dirNames() As String ' Buffer for directory name entries.
          Dim nDir As Integer      ' Number of directories in this path.
          Dim i As Integer         ' For-loop counter.
          Dim Name As String
          Dim Annex As String

          On Error GoTo sysFileERR
          If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
          ' Search for subdirectories.
          nDir = 0
          ReDim dirNames(nDir)
          DirName = Dir(path, vbDirectory Or vbHidden Or vbArchive Or vbReadOnly _
    Or vbSystem)  ' Even if hidden, and so on.
          Do While Len(DirName) > 0
             ' Ignore the current and encompassing directories.
             If (DirName <> ".") And (DirName <> "..") Then
                ' Check for directory with bitwise comparison.
                If GetAttr(path & DirName) And vbDirectory Then
                   dirNames(nDir) = DirName
                   DirCount = DirCount + 1
                   nDir = nDir + 1
                   ReDim Preserve dirNames(nDir)
                   'List2.AddItem path & DirName ' Uncomment to list
                End If                           ' directories.
    sysFileERRCont:
             End If
             DirName = Dir()  ' Get next subdirectory.
          Loop

          ' Search through this directory and sum file sizes.
          FileName = Dir(path & SearchStr, vbNormal Or vbHidden Or vbSystem _
          Or vbReadOnly Or vbArchive)
          'Sheet1.Range("C1").Value2 = path & "\" & FileName
          While Len(FileName) <> 0
             FindFiles = path & "\" & FileName
             FileCount = FileCount + 1
             ' Load List box
            ' Sheet1.Range("A1").Value2 = path & FileName & vbTab & _
                FileDateTime(path & FileName)   ' Include Modified Date
             FileName = Dir()  ' Get next file.
          Wend

          ' If there are sub-directories..
          If nDir > 0 Then
             ' Recursively walk into them
             For i = 0 To nDir - 1
               FindFiles = path & "\" & FileName
             Next i
          End If

    AbortFunction:
          Exit Function
    sysFileERR:
          If Right(DirName, 4) = ".sys" Then
            Resume sysFileERRCont ' Known issue with pagefile.sys
          Else
            MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, , _
             "Unexpected Error"
            Resume AbortFunction
          End If
          End Function



          Sub Find_Files()
          Dim SearchPath As String, FindStr As String, SearchPath1 As String
          Dim FileSize As Long
          Dim NumFiles As Integer, NumDirs As Integer
          Dim Filenames As String, Filenames1 As String
          Dim r As Range
          'Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
          'List2.Clear

          For Each cell In Range("SS")
          SearchPath = Sheet3.Range("B2").Value2
          SearchPath1 = Sheet3.Range("B3").Value2

          FindStr = Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value
          Filenames = FindFiles(SearchPath, FindStr)
          Filenames1 = FindFiles(SearchPath1, FindStr)
          'Sheet1.Range("B1").Value2 = NumFiles & " Files found in " & NumDirs + 1 & _
           " Directories"
          Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value = Filenames
          Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = Filenames1

          'Format(FileSize, "#,###,###,##0") & " Bytes"
          'Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
          Next cell

          End Sub
```

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest using a collection instead of an array.  `Dim dirNames As New VBA.Collection`  Then use the `Add` method to add the filename to the collection.  I then have a helper function to convert a collection to a string using commas.

Comment: Using [Scripting.FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkx696eh(v=vs.84).aspx) seems much simpler when recursing. Just use a simple global string variable and join the matches `sMatches = sMatches & ", " & sNewMatch`. But I wouldn't use comma to separate them as it's a valid filename character.

Comment: @ Bobort - I tried using VBA.Collection but in vain. I didnt work with .Collection previously. Can you please provide me the helper function and the associated code?

Comment: @ Patrick - I tried using something like this -
      
     ` Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`
      
I understand that for recursing it is simpler using Scripting.FileSystemObject. But Can you please tell me why this code is failing in picking two files? Even though it perfoms the same function as that of ScriptingFSO?

Comment: Hi Guys! I have even tried this as well - `dirNames.Add DirName`.But in vain. The problem is in a folder when there are multiple files which meet the match criteria it picks only the first file. Can someobody help me with an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is very old, but it is unanswered. Here is a quick method for finding multiple files and their paths. VBA's `DIR` function isn't really very handy, but CMD's [`DIR` function](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) is well optimized and has a plethora of command line switches to make it return only files (or even just folders) that match your criteria. The trick is to [call `DIR`from a WScript shell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/08/10/how-can-i-call-the-dir-command/) so that the output can be parsed by VBA.

For example, this snippet of code will find every file on your system that starts with *config*.

```
Dim oShell As Object 'New WshShell if you want early binding
Dim cmd As Object 'WshExec if you want early binding
Dim x As Integer
Const WshRunning = 0

Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set cmd = oShell.Exec("cmd /c ""Dir c:\config* /a:-d /b /d /s""")

Do While cmd.Status = WshRunning
    DoEvents
Loop

Debug.Print cmd.StdOut.ReadAll
Set oShell = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
```