# How do I search for a folder and hyperlink its path?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet in which I will keep track of everything that my department 3D prints. I have 3 folders full of one thing each for every part I print: a CAD file, an STL file, and a job folder; all of these contain the same part name which is entered into a cell in the spreadsheet and used for finding all of the files/folders. I like to have my spreadsheet hyperlinked so that I can easily open up any of the three by simply navigating to that part in my spreadsheet.

Now I have the following section of code which takes the name of the printed part from column D, and finds the matching STL in my STL folder, and then hyperlinks it into column U.

```
For i = 4 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'follow through all entries in column D

'--STL------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
If (Len(Cells(i, 4)) > 1) Then
    If (Len(Cells(i, 21)) = 0) Then
        strFile = Dir$(path5w & Cells(i, 4) & "*.stl")
        If (Len(strFile) > 1) Then
            Cells(i, 21).Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 21), path5 & strFile, TextToDisplay:="STL"
        Else
            'No file was found that matches so do nothing
        End If
    Else
    'Already hyperlinked, skip this cell
    End If
Else
'Not a valid Name, do nothing
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I simply copied this chunk of code again and switched the path and switched .STL the extension for my CAD files, and it works great for both of those, but I am getting stuck on the job folders... I have no idea how to get my code to find a folder instead of a file.

I have tried playing around with FileSystemObjects, but I don't fully understand how to use them, and all I can find is an example of how to list every folder inside a folder, and not how to actually search for a specific folder.

I also looked at this example: [VBA to find multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788288/vba-to-find-multiple-files/37872635#37872635) but, again, I run into the problem of not understanding how to use this to search for a folder, rather than listing all folders.

So to help be more clear I will give an example. Lets say I process Part123.stl, when I want to save this, it will create a folder ssys_Part123 and I will save that in my folder named Job Folders. Now I want my program to check cell D4 which says Part123, then navigate to Job Folders, find the folder named ssys_Part123 and hyperlink that folder into V4.

I still don't have a very firm grasp of coding, so any help is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a second (optional) argument for the `Dir` function that allows you to specify the "Atrribute", or file type basically. If you set this to `vbDirectory`, it will explicitly search for folders. Are you trying to hyperlink to the folder then? Or files within the folder?

Comment: This worked when I added vbDirectory... I feel so stupid that I never found these options.

Comment: Can't know everything right away! Glad this worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder name is always going to be ssys_[PartName] then you should be able to just concact the strings to link to the folder instead of trying to look up the folder name.

Comment: This was my original plan, the problem is when people other than me create files, they like to add random nonsense to the names, so I wanted to plan ahead and assume they may not always be exactly the name I expect.